Detecting page change using Spicetify API
I am trying to create an Spicetify extension which triggers some code when a playlist is opened. However, I cannot seem to find any event that I can listen to to trigger it.
The closest thing to it I have is a MutationObserver which picks up the page title change, but, due to it becoming the currently playing song music is playing, it does't always change when opening a different playlist.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
